# Call anonymous PL/SQL with OUT parameter in Groovy

Tags: oracle, groovy

Given the function

```
DECLARE
TYPE t_ids IS TABLE OF PGD.ITEM_CHANGE.id%TYPE;
l_ids t_ids;
BEGIN
    UPDATE PGD.ITEM_CHANGE
    SET    IN_PROCESS = 1
    RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO l_ids;
COMMIT;
END;
```

How do I call this in groovy anonymously (without CREATE PROCEDURE) to get a hold of `L_IDS`?

I'm trying this by putting the above in a String, PROC, and then calling:

```
List<Object> params = [Sql.ARRAY]
sql.callWithRows(PROC, params) {
    result ->
        println result
}
```

And I get the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:125)
...
```

Can someone help me with this syntax?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. [See this thread on OTN (particularly the last two answers)](https://community.oracle.com/thread/226093?start=0&tstart=0). Best of luck.

Comment: This is unfortunately not direct posible in `groovy.sql`. But with a few extensions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230105/4808122) it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the thing that you pasted is not PL/SQL function. It's unnamed block, you cannot extract PL/SQL collection out of unnamed block.

Please convert it to stored function with RETURN statement at the end or procedure with OUT parameter.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this all in the SQL String passed to JDBC, without expressly calling CREATE PROCEDURE or CREATE FUNCTION?  I do not have the CREATE PROCEDURE privilege.