# Reading the Output of DBMS_OUTPUT using Groovy

Tags: java, oracle, groovy, plsql

I'm trying to execute an oracle PL/SQL procedure with groovy but I get exceptions. From what I've understood it is due to these intial lines-

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF 
execute dbms_output.enable(buffer_time);
```

My code looks like this:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
def sql= new Sql(con)
String stmt= " SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF 
execute dbms_output.enable(buffer_time);
declare
//some varaibles
begin
//code
dbms.output.put.line(variable)
end
"
sql.execute(stmt);
```

When I remove the first 3 lines, I get no errors but there will be no output as I'm using `dbms.output.put.line` hence they are neccessary. How do I resolve the SQL Syntax Exception I get from the intial lines?

Comment: "i get exceptions" "i get error" - what exceptions? what errors?

Comment: Using `dbms_output` to return data to a calling application is not something that makes sense in 99.99999% of cases.  `dbms_output` is more of a crude debugging tool.  It would generally make far more sense to, say, declare a function that returned a value and to call that function from your client.  Or a procedure with an `out` parameter.

Comment: The first 3 lines don't work because they're SQL*Plus commands, not PL/SQL. I don't think it will solve your problem, but you could move `dbms_output.enable();` to after `begin` and it would run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution how to read the `DBMS_OUTPUT` in JDBC is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47831073/4808122) and [here](https://gist.github.com/funkman/9c48dbb2452a8dd4fe9e147b9849aa67)

Below is the adapted script using (partly) GroovySQL.

Note that the important part is the call of `dbms_output.get_lines` - without it you'll see no output.

I use (plain) JDBC to call it as it seems some extensions in GroovySQL are required to pass typed ARRAY as an OUT parameter - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230105/4808122)

```
def stmt = """begin 
  dbms_output.enable(); 
  dbms_output.put_line('line 1'); 
  dbms_output.put_line('line 2'); 
end;"""
   
sql.execute(stmt)

int arraySize = 100;
def stmt2 = """begin 
  dbms_output.get_lines(?, ?); /* output array, array size */
end;
"""

def cs = con.prepareCall(stmt2)
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY");
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
cs.setInt(2, arraySize);
cs.execute()

def array = cs.getArray(1);

println array.dump()
array.getArray().each {
   println(it)
}

array.free();
cs.close();
```

It seems that the returned array contains one additional element filled with `null` that should be ignored

```
name = XXXX.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY
max length = 2147483647
length = 3
element[0] = line 1
element[1] = line 2
element[2] = null
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting error

> Fail to construct descriptor: empty Object name

I am not sure how should I pass object name. Below is my groovy call.

```
sql.call("{call dbms_output.get_lines(?, ?)}", [Sql.ARRAY, sql.inout(Sql.INTEGER(100))]){
retVal1, retVal2 ->
log.info(retVal2);
}
```

I think your line `cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY");` is also setting object name.